# API requests are affecting access to the site itself

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, api

This is *really* annoying. I was testing a script that pulls pages from the API according to the published throttle guidelines. Then I went to [StackApps](http://stackapps.com) to do something - and lo and behold, this is what greets me:

> ## We're sorry...
>
> There are an unusual number of requests coming from this IP address.
> To protect our users, we can't process any more requests from this IP address right now.
> We'll restore access as quickly as possible, so try again soon.
> If you believe you have reached this page in error, contact us.

Since when did using an API app affect the site itself??? This is surely a bug.

*Note: I'd have posted this on StackApps, but can't for obvious reasons.*

---

**Update:** I've been able to reproduce this behavior, so it's not a random quirk.

Steps to reproduce:

- Visit http://soapi.info/Code/JS2/latest/Tests/ThrottleTests.htm
- Click on the <kbd>30 requests per 7.0 seconds</kbd> button
- Try to bring up the [StackApps](http://stackapps.com) home page.

Answer (score 2):

So, what you're saying is that you violate the terms of use of the API and are then *surprised* when you get a temporary ban from the network?

If you get a ban from the sites, you'll also be banned from the API too you know.

Comment: @thyrgle - do note that the ban is currently something like 2 minutes, its not a permanent thing.  Might be long enough to get your shoes on.

Comment: @Kevin: You didn't read my question - it says "a script that pulls pages from the API **according to the published throttle guidelines** ". It was **not** violating anything.

Comment: @George - no, you're running code that claims it doesn't.

Comment: @Kevin: Where is this claim?

Comment: @George - claims it doesn't "violate the published guidelines," sorry for the ambiguity.  We've tested this many times and never repro'd with any code that's not Soapi.  All evidence suggests its not a problem on our end, and its ill advised to run at "throttle limits" anyway.  We're not going to waste manpower investigating this, *yet again*.

Comment: *I* don't make any 'claims' that are not backed up by hard numbers that are completely transparent. A spec is a spec. If running at spec is 'ill advised' then the problem is not with the code, it is with the spec or the implementation thereof. In *any* case, 30 request per 7 seconds is not at throttle limits of 30 requests per 5 seconds.

Comment: For those who are interested the tests that 'claim' to run at and well under spec yet fail are located here: http://soapi.info/Code/JS2/latest/Tests/ThrottleTests.htm and the post upon which you are welcomed to post feedback regarding results or the veracity of the tests is here http://stackapps.com/questions/1457/api-usage-triggering-503-too-many-requests

Comment: @Kevin: Well, I've spent time writing an app that doesn't work - **something** needs to get fixed.

Comment: @George - ... you've written a client side [app] that makes 30 reqs a second?  What happens when the user runs another [app]?

Comment: @Kevin: I don't know. If it helps at all, you can find it here: http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com/display2.php

Comment: @George - ... no, I mean if your [app] is client side and is making 30 requests a second it will **break** the instant the user has another [app] installed.  Frankly, its misunderstandings like this that make me want to rescind the throttle documentation and phrase it like "The # of requests X users would reasonably make in Y seconds".  This obsession with making the maximum number of requests possible is completely missing the point.

Comment: george's app uses the default soapi.js2 throttle settings of max 30 requests per 7 seconds with no more than 10 concurrent active requests and it seems to work just fine. no one is obsessed with squeezing the most requests and this has been made clear. you published a spec and everyone is making efforts to respect it. The issue of multiple apps is a straw man in this conversation, in another it would be story that supports server side throttling.